# How might I simplify this CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working with WordPress and have been killing myself tonight with this CSS. I finally have gotten things to work as follows however I'm sure there's a way to clean it up. I've tried several articles without luck, formatting and reformatting. Anyways, here's my code:

```
.postid-5648 #masthead {
    display: none;
}
.postid-5648 #colophon {
    display: none;
}
.postid-5365 #masthead {
    display: none;
}
.postid-5365 #colophon {
    display: none;
}
```

I've tried things like this, without luck:

```
.postid-5648, .postid-5365, #masthead, #colophon {
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Grouping selectors`](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rules_group_sel.htm) - If more than one CSS selectors have same CSS declarations, they can be grouped together.

```
selector1, selector2, selector3,.................................. selectorN 
{property : value; .......... }
```

Where **selector1, ......... selectorN** are different selectors. Notice that here selectors are separated with "**,**"combinators.

```
.postid-5648 #masthead,
.postid-5648 #colophon,
.postid-5365 #masthead,
.postid-5365 #colophon {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class start with `.postid-`, you can used `*` selector like this,

```
[class*="postid-"] #masthead,
[class*="postid-"] #colophon {
   display: none;
}
```

```css
[class*="postid-"] #masthead,
[class*="postid-"] #colophon {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="postid-5648">
  <div id="colophon">colophon</div>
  <div id="masthead">masthead</div>
</div>
<div class="postid-5365">
  <div id="masthead">masthead</div>
  <div id="colophon">colophon</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group them all together like:

```css
.postid-5648 #masthead,
.postid-5648 #colophon,
.postid-5365 #masthead,
.postid-5365 #colophon {
    display: none;
}
```

This enables subsequent contributors to have a clear understanding of the flow of the document.

Just go through [CSS Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/css/)

Answer (score 0):

> The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

```
[class^="postid-"] #masthead,
[class^="postid-"] #colophon {
     display: none;
}
```

**Note:**`[class*="postid-"]` is wrong because accept `xxpostidxx-5648`.

Comment: This would be nice but I only need it for about 4 postid-'s